# Why does a branch base reset after an interactive rebase?

Tags: git

I have a master branch, and I branch out to my feature branch:

```
A -> B -> C (master)
          | -> D -> E (feature)
```

If there was work on master, I want to rebase the feature branch onto the new master, this way:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature
git rebase master
result:
A -> B -> C -> F -> G (master)
                    | -> D -> E (feature)
```

Now I want to do some interactive rebasing over feature (for example, fixup):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
...
pick efgh456 message for commit D
f abcd123 message for commit E
save and quit
```

Expected result:

```
A -> B -> C -> F -> G (master)
                    | -> DE (feature)
```

Actual result:

```
A -> B -> C -> F -> G (master)
          | -> DE (feature)
```

What is the git explanation here?

Comment: You should include what you actually did after starting the intereactive rebase.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added an extra detail (fixup inside the interactive rebase)

Comment: After `git rebase master` but before the interactive rebase, can you show the output of `git log master feature --graph ` ?

Comment: In the output of the interactive rebase, which commit message is shown on the line that is "..." ? (If your commits are all linear it should be G, if not linear, then it's possibly F, and if the rebase onto `master` didn't work as intended it might be `C`.)

Answer (score 1):

As said in other answers and comments: you provided only partial information, and not enough to identify your issue with certainty.

Here is however one blind guess :

If you have *merge commits* in the mix, you may experience some weirdness that could fit what you describe:

- `git log` alone would still display a linear sequence of commits, which may lead you to believe your *history* is linear,
- `HEAD~3` (or `~n`) would point to a commit farther behind than what you think,
- the default behavior of `git rebase` is to completely drop merge commits from the sequence it rewrites

So you may end up with a rebased history starting from a commit older than you expect.

One possibility matching your example description:

If your history after rebasing is actually:

```
* E
* D
* G
|\
| * F
|/
* C
* B
* A
```

then

- `HEAD~3` would actually be `C` (not `F`),
- `git rebase -i HEAD~3` would ask for instructions to replay `F D E` (`G` would be discarded),
- and the result would be a linear history on top of `C`.

---

One recommendation:

when you want to see the history *for yourself* using `git log` (as opposed to: use the output of `git log` in a script), *always* add the `--graph` option. This will allow you to actually see forks & merges in your history.

My go-to command to see the history of my repo is :

```
git log --oneline --graph
```

One other suggestion:
count your commits (on the correct history graph), or use branch names instead of `HEAD~n`.

With the example you describe in your question: merging `D` and `E` together just requires `git rebase -i HEAD~2` or `git rebase -i master`, and this would create one commit on top of `G`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are no merge commits, and I'm using the correct graph representation. The example I showed is easily reproducible: 
1. Create a master branch, add a few commits in. (master, A, B, C, F, G)
2. checkout some C commit and branch out of it (feature branch).
3. Add a few more commits into the new  (D, E).
4. Interactive rebase to fixup D and E.

Comment: Ok, that was a blind shot anyway. I'm afraid the sequence of actions you mention produce the result I expect on my machine (commits squashed on top of `G`). If you really need an answer to a repeatable issue on your side, please provide a script which highlights your issue, or give a more thorough description of the actions you run.

Comment: @Mickey in the question you claimed you did `git rebase master` first, which should have made the graph you showed (with D's parent being G), and then you did `git rebase -i @~3`. But in the comment you made on this answer with the steps to reproduce, it sounds like you are skipping those extra steps of pulling `master` and then rebasing `feature` onto the latest `master`, which would explain why `feature` wasn't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You never showed us the steps you took after starting the interactive rebase, but if you just want to squash the top 2 most recent commits, you only need:

```
# from feature branch
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This should bring up an editor looking something like the following:

```
pick efgh456 message for commit D
pick abcd123 message for commit E
```

Edit this file and change to:

```
pick efgh456 message for commit D
squash abcd123 message for commit E
```

Then close/save the editor, which will start the rebase.  Resolve any merge conflicts which might occur.  Now your history should look like:

```
master: A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G
                                       \
feature:                                DE (single squashed commit)
```

Comment: this is what I meant by using fixup, i'll edit the question to make it clearer.
My history should look this way, but it looks the way I showed in my post...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative from Tim's approach could be to just merge and squash... I normally do it this way:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git merge main-branch
# assuming the merge was successful, if it's not successful, then
# you need to wrap it up and commit to continue.
git reset --soft main-branch
git commit -m "Here's a single commit for my feature"
```

If it is a short branch, I would probably rebase... if it's a longer branch, I would go this route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not looking for a solution to the unwanted base change, rather than an explanation